# FromUriAttribute replacement in ASP.NET Core - specifically for parameter aliasing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an MVC Controller with the following API:

```
public CustomObject Get([FromUri] float lat, [FromUri(Name="long")] float longitude, string userKey = null)
```

This works, but requires the compatibility shim since FromUri is deprecated.

How do I replicate the "aliasing" behavior of the longitude parameter with proper ASP.NET Core API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Bind Attribute as an alternative solution

```
public CustomObject Get(float lat, [Bind(Prefix = "long")]float longitude, string userKey = null)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow--could you clarify how this helps with this asker's problem? They'd like to rename a parameter, not change a route.

Comment: This is a tenable workaround but a) I'd like the request to adhere to the ?lat=0&long=0 format and b) I don't see how userKey is addressed

Comment: @Malachi I misread the question and have provided an alternative solution. Hope that helps

Comment: What to do when dealing with a [complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343700/how-to-use-fromquery-attribute-get-a-complex-object)?