# How to use FromQuery Attribute get a complex object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to use FromQueryAttribute get a complex object?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] DataGridRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

The DataGridRequest class like this:

```
public class DataGridRequest
{
    public DataGridPager Pager { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class DataGridPager
{
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

How to write the uri?

Comment: How did you reference [FromQuery]?  I am getting errors A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces.

Comment: Reference this assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, I only used it in asp.net core.

Comment: It is also mandatory to define a { get; set; } on your property. otherwise it can't get mapped.

Comment: There is a DOT trick to bind a complex model for the get method : ...&Pager.Size=3&...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try a Get request like this

```
controller?Size=1&Index=2
```

Also try to use `[FromUri]` instead `[FromQuery]`. The `[FromUri]` attribute tries to bind the object properties to the query string properties by name

Comment: `FromUri` doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core. Any substitute?

Comment: @Shimmy Yeah, there are `[FromQuery]` to get parameter from a request query string and `[FromRoute]`

Comment: You can also use [FromQuery] to bind to complex object e.g. `public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] MyFilterModel _filters)` Refer this link : http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Do this to set data for subobjects using [FromQuery]:

```
controller?Pager.Size=1&Pager.Index=2
```