# FromQuery Nested Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

How can we bind nested properties from query?

Example model:

```
public class X {
    public string PropA { get;set; }
    public string PropB { get;set: }
    public Y ClassY { get;set; }
}

public class Y {
    [FromQuery(Name = "prop1")]
    public string Prop1 { get;set; }
    public string Prop2 { get;set; }
}
```

Class x gets passed into the Controller Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery]X classX)
```

Value of prop1 model y doesn't get bound -> class x is always null.

I would to build my query like so https://host.example/api/x?prop1=example

As an alternative I can flatten out the models but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Is your code C#?  I don't recognize it.

Comment: Yea I just wrote some pseudo want me to write it in C# syntax?

Comment: That and I've never see the attribute used directly on the object, [only on the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343700/how-to-use-fromquery-attribute-get-a-complex-object).  Does it work on the property?

Comment: I updated the question. It works on properties of class x. Class y i don't know because class X is always null when trying to pass a property of class y. It's used to give an alias to the property. You can then use this alias in your url query parameter.

Comment: Did you try something like this ?y.prop1=value

Comment: Works! Thanks! Do you have any idea whether its possible to map it to prop1?

Comment: You need to provide the controllers signature.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: @user2963570 I had the same problem. I've solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75684248/9409429).