# How to use FromQuery with nested models?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a view model for Home page like this:

```
public class LandingViewModel : BaseHomeViewModel
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<MissionCardViewModel> MissionCards { get; set; } = null!;

    // Search model
    public SearchViewModel Search { get; set; } = new SearchViewModel();
}
```

Here as you can see we have a nested model `Search` which will be used for searching. It contains the following fields:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string? Query { get; set; }

    public Country SelectedCountry { get; set; } = null!;
    
    [FromQuery(Name = "sortBy")]
    public SortBy SortMissionsBy { get; set; } = SortBy.None;

    public List<Filter> Cities { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<Filter> Themes { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<Filter> Skills { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

As you can see I have applied the `[FromQuery]` attribute to SortMissionsBy field. And in the html side I've also given the input field a `name="sortBy"`. However, the model binding does not work. It works perfectly if use the usual `asp-for="Search.SortMissionsBy"` which will generate a name of **Search.SortMissionsBy**, which I don't want as it's too big for a URL.

So, how can I use a simple name for query string like **sortBy** while also binding the data present in a nested Model like `SearchViewModel`? I don't want to flatten my `LandingViewModel` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. So, it works like this:

1. Give an empty name to the nested viewmodel like `[FromQuery(Name = "")]`. In this way the nested properties will be accessible without writing the name of viewmodel. For e.g., We can just write `cityId` instead of `Search.cityId`.
2. Give the properties in nested viewmodel whatever name you like. For e.g., `cityId`.

Now we can easily make a GET request with `?cityId=<some-id>` and it will be bound to the nested viewmodel's property `Search.cityId`.

Please tell me in comments if it works for you as well.

**Full code**

```
public class LandingViewModel : BaseHomeViewModel
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<MissionCardViewModel> MissionCards { get; set; } = null!;

    // Search model
    
    // Step: 1
    [FromQuery(Name = "")]
    public SearchViewModel Search { get; set; } = new SearchViewModel();
}
```

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string? Query { get; set; }

    public Country SelectedCountry { get; set; } = null!;
    
    // Step: 2
    [FromQuery(Name = "sortBy")]
    public SortBy SortMissionsBy { get; set; } = SortBy.None;

    ...
}
```