# How to create a routing in asp.net-core-webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement a basic routing in my .net core web api.

I have a controller like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    //out of the box
    [HttpGet("[action]")] //get the list
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Get()
    {
      //omitted
    }

    //added: request detail request///
    [HttpGet("[action]/{fooid}")]
    public Foo Get(string fooid)
    {
      //omitted
    }
}
```

I trying to make the following routes work:

One for the details:

```
http://localhost:2724/api/Product/Get?fooid=myfoo1
```

And a general one for the listing:

```
http://localhost:2724/api/Product/Get
```

The problem is that the call with the `?fooid=` ends up at the `IEnumerable` version and I can't seem to get it right.

---

I tried various syntactic variations to overcome this, e.g.: `[HttpGet("{fooid}")]` but this doesn't seem to help.

I know I can just rename the method, but I am doing this as an exercise.

I also know it's not done to ask for documentation, but any help on this matter is welcome.

I also tried to add a route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute( //default
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "fooid",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{fooid?}");

        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
```

I tried some of the methods as described [here](http://vb-net.com/AspNet-DocAndSamples-2017/aspnetcore/mvc/models/formatting.htm), but no success.

Can you give me some directions?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/routing-in-restful-apis-using-net-core/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL for the parameter version is incorrect. It needs to be the same as you have written in the HttpGet attribute e.g.

```
http://localhost:2724/api/Product/Get/myfoo1
```

If you do want the parameter to be passed as ?fooId=myFoo then you need to declare your method as:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public Foo Get([FromUri]string fooId)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay... that seems to fix it.Thank you.

Comment: One side mark: n asp .net core 2, `[FromUri]` seems depricated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974734/fromuriattribute-replacement-in-asp-net-core-specifically-for-parameter-aliasi#36975487